# Trigger an Event if 2 or more input field are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a condition that if the two fields are not empty it would display the button. My problem is how to execute the event because it only works onload or upon loading of the website. I tried using keyup

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="username" required="true">
<input type="email" id="email"  required="true" >
<button type="submit" id="login">
Sign Up
</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#email').is(':empty') && $('#username').is(':empty')){
    $('#login').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#login').show();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0pohLeb/1/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `input` event.

```
// Bind `input` event on both the inputs
$('#email, #username').on('input', function() {
    // toggle: If argument passed is 
    //         true:  show
    //         false: hide
    $('#login').toggle($('#email').val() && $('#username').val());
}).trigger('input'); // Trigger event to call on page load
```

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** use `.is(':empty')` to check for emptiness of the values, it is just for checking if the **tag is empty** and doesn't contain any children. Instead you need to use:

```
$(input).val().trim().length === 0
```

So your code becomes:

```
if ($('#email').val().trim().length === 0 && $('#username').val().trim().length === 0) {
```

And also, you need to attach this to a better event, say, on `keyup` of the input:

**Final Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#email').val().trim().length === 0 || $('#username').val().trim().length === 0) {
    $('#login').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#login').show();
  }
  $("#email, #username").keyup(function () {
    if ($('#email').val().trim().length === 0 && $('#username').val().trim().length === 0) {
      $('#login').hide();
    }
    else {
      $('#login').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it does work but the button get shown even if only one field is filled up

Comment: @JeVic Change `&&` to `||` sorry. Here you go: [**Demo**](http://output.jsbin.com/yazamanufi).

Comment: `.length === 0` is irrelevant here as empty string is falsy in JS. And `trigger()` too, to shorten the code.

Comment: @Tushar Sure. `:)` Just to be sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope this helps..:)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('change', 'input', validate);
  validate();

  function validate() {
    var inputLength = 0;
    $('input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('type') == 'text' || $(this).attr('type') == 'email' || $(this).attr('type') == 'password') {

        $(this).val() == '' ? inputLength-- : inputLength++;
      }

    });
    inputLength >= 2 ? notEmpty() : isEmpty();

  };

  function notEmpty() {

    $('#login').show();

  }

  function isEmpty() {

    $('#login').hide();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" required="true">
<input type="email" id="email" required="true">
<button type="submit" id="login">
  Sign Up
</button>
```

fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/j6y2d1ur/1/